# Ubuntu Network configuration setting and Windows

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, ip

Suppose I have connected to a Network having Static IP after that connected to a Network having DHCP, When I go back to previos network having static one I find lost my setting (IPV4). Probably Windows has one place to set Network configuration.But in ubunto/Linux there are different static IP configuration corresponding to different Networks.How can we do this fow windows?or is there any setting availble for windows

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to change the static IP of your windows computer:
Go to the Network and Sharing Center in the Control panel
Click change adapter settings
Right-Click on Local Area Connection and select properties
Click Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) then properties
Select the radio button for Use the following IP address
Enter your IP address
Click OK

If this fails then return to Obtain IP automatically

Comment: Thanks for Reply.I was asking that Suppose  I have connected to a Network having Static IP after that  connected to a Network having DHCP, When I go back to previos network having  static one  I find lost my setting (IPV4). Probably Windows has one place to set Network configuration.But in ubunto/Linux there are different static IP configuration corresponding to different Networks.How can we do this fow windows?or is there any setting availble for windows.